# read flag argument value ip address

Tags: go

I am trying to read an ip address from arguments:

```
var ipaddress_string string
flag.StringVar(&ipaddress_string, "ip", "127.0.0.1", "an ip string var")
ipaddress := net.ParseIP(ipaddress_string)
fmt.Println(ipaddress)
```

Executing with:
app -ip=10.0.0.1 
or 
app -ip="10.0.0.1"

But 127.0.0.1 always come out?

Comment: It looks like you need to call `flag.Parse` from [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/).

Comment: You are so right my friend :-) Thanks. Can I do more than voting this as useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/), you need to make a call to `flags.Parse()` after binding all flags to variables. The following is a complete, runnable example:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    var ipaddress_string string
    flag.StringVar(&ipaddress_string, "ip", "127.0.0.1", "an ip string var")
    flag.Parse()
    ipaddress := net.ParseIP(ipaddress_string)
    fmt.Println(ipaddress)
}
```